# IBM Mobile First Platform Windows Phone post request Media type not supported

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, windows-mobile, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I am getting following error on sending post request in IBM Mobile First Platform 7.1.0 from Windows mobile. This is working fine on Android and iOS.

My request content type is `application/json` but it throws error for 
`x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
The system cannot find any method in the com.my_app.contract.adapter.ContractResource class 
that consumes application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 
media type. Verify that a method exists that consumes 
the  media type specified.

The following error occurred during the invocation of the 
handlers chain: WebApplicationException (415 - Unsupported Media Type) 
with message 'null' while processing POST request sent to http://192.168.1.185:10080/Code/adapters/contact/
mycontact/record/save
```

Server Side Code

```
@POST
@Path("/record/save")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
@OAuthSecurity(scope = "AppRealm")
public Object save(List<Dto> dtoList) throws Exception {
//Code
}
```

Mobile Side Code

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/contact/mycontact/record/save", WLResourceRequest.POST);
resourceRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
resourceRequest.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
resourceRequest.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
resourceRequest.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');
```

Comment: In which iFix version of MFP 7.1 you are facing this issue ?

Comment: @VittalPai We are using Mobile Studio Plugin 7.1.0

Comment: Are you using iFix version or GA version of 7.1.0? If its iFix, Can you tell me the iFix version number ?

Comment: @VittalPai we are not using any iFIX. Can you help how to use it?

Comment: Please use latest iFix release of MFP 7.1. You can download latest iFix release from IBM Fix Central website.